# VSCode Not Using Conda Python

Tags: visual-studio-code, conda

I saw a previous and related issue for VSCode, but the thread is closed:  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/7293

I have been using VS Code for some time and the behavior always was as expected.  However, over the last week or so, after activating a conda environment and a terminal in VS Code, the terminal within VS Code uses the system default, and not the conda environment as it previosuly did.

I am very stumped.  Any thoughts as to what could have caused VS Code to ignore the conda environment's python interpreter?  If I use the terminal (MacOS), the conda environment behaves as expected.

[image]